# Copy , Insert rows and Paste data from two sheets to third sheet

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy, paste

I have data in two sheets one sheet having customer and another having material data. In both sheets, unique column in Base Cust. In customer sheet, each Base cust has 1 or more different customers and material sheet has same like each Base cust has different materials. I want to consolidate both sheets data in new sheet.

For example -

Sheet1 has following data

```
Base cust   customer

00301        112501
00301        112502
00302        112503
00302        112504
```

Sheet 2 has following data

```
Base Cust    Material

00301        M12113501
00301        M12113502
00302        M12113501
00302        M12113502
```

In New sheet data should looks like

```
Base Cust     Cust          Material

00301        112501         M12113501
00301        112501         M12113502
00301        112502         M12113501
00301        112502         M12113502
00302        112503         M12113501
00302        112503         M12113502
00302        112504         M12113501
00302        112504         M12113502
```

I need your help if you can provide me VBA codes to prepare this kind of above data.

```
Sub Macro() 

    Dim lastrowone, lastrowtwo As Long 
    lastrowone = Sheets("1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    lastrowtwo = Sheets("2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    For I = 2 To lastrowone 
        For J = 2 To lastrowtwo 
            If Sheets("1").Cells(I, 1).Value = Sheets("2").Cells(J, 1).Value Then 
                Sheets("1").Cells(I, 1).EntireRow.Copy 
                Sheets("3").Cells(I, 1).Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 
             End If 
        Next J 
    Next I 

End Sub
```

Comment: Typically people post here with existing code they're having a problem with - that's typically the best way to get help.  If you don't know *any* VBA (or at least not enough to even make a start on your problem) then this is not a good place to get your code written.  please review [ask]

Comment: I know bit VBA but for this scenario needs help....THanks

Comment: Here I am trying codes. But exact data is not getting copied here.

Comment: Sub Macro()
Dim lastrowone, lastrowtwo As Long
lastrowone = Sheets("1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrowtwo = Sheets("2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 2 To lastrowone For J = 2 To lastrowtwo
 If Sheets("1").Cells(I, 1).Value = Sheets("2").Cells(J, 1).Value Then             Sheets("1").Cells(I, 1).EntireRow.Copy  Sheets("3").Cells(I, 1).Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
             End If  Next J
Next I

End Sub

Comment: Voted to re-open after code added...